Edge states in Topological Insulators
I have been trying to solve for edge states in a topological insulator.  Consider a 2-D  system with two regions, $x>0$ and $x<0$, in $x-y$ plane with trivial and non trivial topology respectively. Because of the this, our system is no longer translationally invariant along $x$- axis while $y$-axis's periodic boundary conditions(PBC) is left intact. We expect the solutions to be a plane wave along $y$-axis modulated by some function of $x$.
I have also looked at  worked out examples of this problem, on page 6 of the linked note for example, but have a trouble following it. I have two doubts. First,  they use the Bloch Hamiltonian which was derived when PBC along x was still intact and secondly,  why does it make sense to replace $k_x$ by $i\partial_x$ when $k_x$ is crystal momentum and $\partial_x$ is momentum in space representation?
Thank you very much.

So this is for those people who might need it in the future. Basically, you do this thing called Envelope Function Approximation. This is neatly discussed in chapter 7 of this book
